# What determines an Xcode Project's developmentRegion setting?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm working on a C++ project using Xcode with another developer. Every time he opens the xcodeproj, his version of Xcode adds `developmentRegion = English;` to the project.pbxproj file inside the xcodeproj. Every time I open the xcodeproj, my version of Xcode removes the `developmentRegion = English;` line from the project.pbxproj file.

We have the xcode project committed to source control, and the constant back and forth of this line is quite annoying. How can I configure my system so that Xcode doesn't try to remove the line? Or, alternatively, how can he configure his system so that Xcode doesn't try to add the line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's related to your Xcode version, version 3.2.4 started adding that string, while previous versions don't (and are are removing it).

Comment: The 3.2.4 release notes say "Xcode no longer incorrectly sets DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE to 'English' in Run Script build phases. This used to happen even when the CFBundleDevelopmentRegion key in the target’s Info.plist file is set to a different value, such as 'en'. 8358625" - seems to be some connection here, although I don't know why this has now become a key in the proj files.

Comment: Upgrading from 3.2.3 to 3.2.4 fixed it. Thanks!